# Permanent Fix to Unknown Filesystem Error and GrUB Rescue

Tags: grub

So, a few months ago, GrUB on my Linux Mint machine updated. This computer (an HP laptop) has both Windows and Mint. When I installed Mint, GrUB worked fine, but when GrUB updated and I would try to go boot into Mint, I started getting an unknown filesystem error then would get put into GrUB rescue. I found the solution to be able to boot in Mint to be:

```
grub rescue> set boot=(hd0,gpt8)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

(Mint is installed on my 8th partition.)

Then the regular grub boot menu would appear, and I could get into Mint. Now, I have to type that list of commands in every time I try to boot into Mint. While looking for a permanent solution, I found the most common answer to be:

```
> sudo update-grub
> sudo grub-install
```

or

```
> sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

While update-grub works without issue, grub-install gives me errors of:

```
-> grub-install.real: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
-> grub-install.real: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
-> grub-install.real: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

From here, I have not been able to find an solutions.

Does anyone know what I might have to do to solve this? I am beginning to wonder if the answer is either very simple and I have overlooked it or every fundamental and beyond what I have knowledge of.